# karate Gatling- reporting questions

Tags: karate

Currently, performance test reports from karate gatling are stored in gatling folder under target with the format of {simualtionclassname-timestamp}. I would like community inputs on below questions around reporting-

1. Is it possible to customize the folder structure for gatling reporting? I was thinking of having one folder named gatling-reports ( just like karate-reports). This would be helpful to retrieve any info from the last run logs.
2. Is there any way to compare the results against the defined SLA or even the previous results?

[image]